# ASP Net Core Validation - Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely

Tags: validation, asp.net-core

I am using .net core MVC app with the following

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.4",
        "portable-net451+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
```

aspnetcore version 1.0.1 and am getting an error in the model validation when receiving a json payload.

Controller method

```
[HttpPut()]
public IActionResult Put([FromBody] Supplier entity)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid || entity == null)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    var updated = _Service.Upsert(entity);
    return Ok(updated);
}
```

Error Trace (content reduced for brevity)

> Error: Unable to process request
>   'http://localhost:58026/api/v1/Suppliers2'.
>   System.InsufficientExecutionStackException: Insufficient stack to
>   continue executing the program safely. This can happen from having too
>   many functions on the call stack or function on the stack using too
>   much stack space.    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.EnsureSufficientExecutionStack()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.Visit(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, String key, Object model)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitChildren(IValidationStrategy
>   strategy)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitComplexType()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.Visit(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, String key, Object model)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitChildren(IValidationStrategy
>   strategy)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitComplexType()

I have narrowed the issue down to the fact that there is a DBGeography object in the object model as follows:

```
public partial class Address
{
    public Address() { }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Content removed for brevity

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string AdminRegion1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(30)]
    public string AdminRegion2 { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(GeoPointConverter))]
    public DbGeography Location { get; set; }

}
```

If the json posted for the model sets the DBGeography to null then everything works correctly.  The stack overflow only occurs when the Location is set to a valid DBGeography.

From the stack trace it appears to be the model validation in the pipeline that is causing the issue.

Does anyone know why the DBGeography type would cause a stack overflow in the model validation?

The documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation#custom-validation provides examples of custom validation which I have tried but they fail to be called and I still get the stack overflow.  Also does anyone know how to disable the validation as there is no mention of this in the guide.

I would be grateful for any suggestions on how to track down the problem

Comment: How would custom validation be related to a custom Json Converter? The address model you posted has no validation at all

Comment: Tseng, thanks for the reply.  As I mentioned it is not the json converter that is causing the problem.  I have removed that reference from the question to prevent confusion.  Regarding the model as mentioned I had removed other properties for brevity but I have added some back that have validation on them.  Any idea why the DBGeography could be causing the stack overflow?

Comment: Should you maybe add `DbGeography ` object to the post? Have you tried to update to ASP.NET Core 1.1 to see if it works there?

Comment: Does the `DbGeography` instance references any parent objects?

Comment: Hi Henk,  The DBGeography object is a Microsoft class System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography.  I guess you are correct and there is some sort of sircular reference going on in this type.  If there was a way to turn of the model validation for this type it would solve my issue.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov, I have just upgraded to 1.1 and the same issue occurs.  I am guessing that the model validation is not coping with circular references as suggested by Henk.

Comment: Create you simplified post model to receive and validate in controller and map it to the entity with AutoMapper or manually.

Comment: I have created issue on the aspnet.core git repo in case it comes up with any other objects. https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2024

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov,  Many thanks for the suggestion.  I will look up Automapper as I have not seen that mentioned before.  Any links that could help?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started. It is made for mapping view models to entities mostly.